# Java serialization in memory instead of file

Tags: java, serialization

I learned about serialization in Java and how it can be done by saving object's generated byte code into file and then be deserialized back into an instance of the same class. But my question is can this be done without the files? Maybe to get a reference where is all that data stored in memory instead of file?

What I need is a history of an object's state (not just a reference to it) and to be able to bring this past state back at a later time. Thanks

Comment: Sure. Just write it to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, for example.

Comment: "*how it can be done by saving object's generated byte code into file*", I don't think this statement is true, you should re-read the serialization.